# Mac OS X : lldb unable to attach, gdb codesigning

Tags: macos

For Mac OS X 10.12.4:

I have a mac user that needs to use a debugger -- either `lldb` or `/opt/local/bin/ggdb` (from MacPorts).

I added the user to the `_developer` group.
I ran the `/usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable` command.

My account can use `lldb` now, but the other account still cannot, and gets the "`unable to attach`" error.

For `ggdb`, I created a codesigning certificate, but `ggdb` still cannot attach to a running process.

So what do I need to do to get `lldb` working for an `_developer`?
What can I do to get `ggdb` working?

Please request information you need in the comments, and I will update the question with any new information.

```
bll-mac:bll$ codesign -d -v -v /opt/local/bin/ggdb
Executable=/opt/local/bin/ggdb
Identifier=org.gnu.gdb
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=47772 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1489+2 location=embedded
Signature size=1557
Authority=gdb-cert
Signed Time=2017 -04-05, 15:26:16 
Info.plist entries=4
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=88
```